# Error AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. in xamarin.IOS

Tags: iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

> Error       AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>
> MessagingRemoteException: An error occured on client Build480760 while executing a reply for topic xvs/Build/4.8.0.760/execute-task/neoFly_Montana.iOS/0c8c9ea002fIBTool
>
> ArgumentException: Failed to parse PList data type:
>
> ArgumentException: Must specify valid information for parsing in the string.   neoFly_Montana.iOS

I have a xamarin.forms project, and today, with no reason, I can't run my project in a physical device, only emulator....
when I try the device, I see the errors above...
Someone can help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would *assume* that your macOS auto-updated to Xcode **9.3** which is not currently supported (Open Xcode and check the version).

You will need to downgrade to `9.2` until Microsoft/Xamarin releases a supporting Xamarin.iOS version.

Xcode (via `.xip`) is available via your Apple developer account @

- http://developer.apple.com/download/more/

> MARCH 29, 2018
>
> As announced on Apple’s developer news site, Apple has just released Xcode 9.3 final.
>
> The Xamarin team is proceeding as usual to test for compatibility and publish updated versions of Xamarin.iOS and the Visual Studio Tools for Xamarin to align with the new version of Xcode. Keep an eye on this blog for status updates.

- https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-xcode-9-3/

Comment: Thanks, in fact my xcode is 9.3 now. Any idea or help about how can I downgrade it?

Comment: @JoycedeLanna download 9.2 from the Apple developer site (see link in my answer). Before unarchiving the download, copy the Xcode.app 9.3 so you can restore it later (so you do not have to waste 14GB of bandwidth/time to download it again) or rename the unarchived 9.2 version and point the Xamarin iOS options to look at it instead of the default Xcode location

Comment: my project is in my visual studio in my windows and it is connected to my mac...do I need to update my xamarin.ios in my vs studio in my windows as well? because yesterday xamarin updated but the error still here for me...I updated only xamarin.ios in my mac because my windoes doesnt have memory

Comment: I need...I saw in xamarin site

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error after updating Xcode on the connected iOS build machine (I'm using VS2017 on Windows).

The simple (but not immediately obvious) solution in my case was:-

1. Run Xcode (which triggered a prompt to update additional components).
2. Complete this additional component update.
3. Restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: Restart **Visual Studio**.

Answer (score 0):

- try to close the Visual studio
- remove Everything within Bin Folder
  ( Project/project.IOS/bin )
- remove Everything within Debug Folder  (
  Project/project.IOS/debug )
- Open Visual studio again and try to run the Project Again

this helps me :)